# Do the CRM SDK DLL's Use the deprecated OData v2? E.g. IOrganizationService in Plugins

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Microsoft is deprecating the "Organization Data Service" aka "OData v2 service"

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/odata-v2-0-service-removal-date-announcement/

The guidance and explanation focuses on checking for explicit usage of the URL `/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc`, says to check CRM Web Resource JavaScript files.

**But what about the CRM .NET SDK's used in Plugins, or Console Apps?** How do we know if those are older/deployed a while ago, maybe using the "Organization Data Service"?

Or is it a given that the .NET SDK `IOrganizationService` does NOT use this endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the .NET SDK never used the OData 2.0 endpoint, so .NET parts using the .NET SDK (plugins, console apps, custom workflow activities) are not impacted by the OData 2.0 removal.

The OData 2.0 removal mostly affects JavaScript and Web Resources, if you are using a third-party component (like a custom library and not the official CRM SDK) you need to check them just to be sure.

Comment: If it never used the OData 2.0 endpoint, what is it using? I'm having a hard time finding authoritative documentation/reference about that. Is it using the "2011 older SOAP web service" basically?

Comment: the .NET Framework SDK used SOAP

Comment: The CrmServiceClient and the Dataverse ServiceClient use the organization API.
 
In the case of the dataverse ServiceClient, to surface the Organization API it uses a tweaked version of SOAP , OData4 and in some cases and surfaces, GRPC.

As Guido indicated,  OData2 only ever presented in examples for the JS Caller API,

note that the endpoint surfaced the Odata2 Endpoint is /xrmservices/2011/organizationDATA.svc. 

The SOAP endpoint is 
/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc?web

Comment: [This article](https://prasannavadlamudiblog.wordpress.com/2018/06/09/web-api-organization-service-and-organization-data-service-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/) explains the various services.